# How can I remove duplicates in an F# sequence without using references

Tags: f#

I have a sorted sequence and want to go through it and return the unique entries in the sequence. I can do it using the following function, but it uses reference variables and I don't think it's the correct way of solving the problem.

```
    let takeFirstCell sectors = 
        let currentRNCId = ref -1
        let currentCellId = ref -1
        seq {
            for sector in sectors do
                if sector.RNCId <> !currentRNCId || sector.CellId <> !currentCellId then
                    currentRNCId := sector.RNCId
                    currentCellId := sector.CellId
                    yield sector
        }
```

How can I do this in a functional way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[1;1;1;2;2;2;3;3;3]
|> Seq.distinctBy id
|> printfn "%A"
```

Answer (score 8):

`Seq.distinct (1::[1..5])` returns `seq [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 5):

`distinct` and `distinctBy` both use `Dictionary` and therefore require hashing and a bit of memory for storing unique items. If your sequence is already sorted, you can use the following approach (similar to yours). It's nearly twice as fast and has constant memory use, making it usable for sequences of any size.

```
let distinctWithoutHash (items:seq<_>) =
  seq {
    use e = items.GetEnumerator()
    if e.MoveNext() then
      let prev = ref e.Current
      yield !prev
      while e.MoveNext() do
        if e.Current <> !prev then 
          yield e.Current
          prev := e.Current
  }

let items = Seq.init 1000000 (fun i -> i / 2)
let test f = items |> f |> (Seq.length >> printfn "%d")

test Seq.distinct        //Real: 00:00:01.038, CPU: 00:00:01.435, GC gen0: 47, gen1: 1, gen2: 1
test distinctWithoutHash //Real: 00:00:00.622, CPU: 00:00:00.624, GC gen0: 44, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

I couldn't figure out a way to use `mutable`s instead of `ref`s (short of hand-coding an enumerator), <strike>which I'm sure would speed it up considerably</strike> (I tried it--it makes no difference).

Comment: mutables aren't allowed to escape their environment (placed on the heap to be referenced by a closure) and since computation expressions like `seq` (well, `seq` gets some special compiler optimizations) desugar to a chain of continuations, you must use `ref` (the F# designers wanted us to be able to reason about mutables as purely local).

Comment: ... so I think even if mutables were allowed to escape their environment, they would probably not give a performance increase since likely they'd be allocated on the heap (though another possible implementation is just to keep the stackframe alive after returning).

Comment: Oh, and regarding your `distinctWithoutHash` implementation, another nice thing about it is that it is lazy!

Comment: @Stephen: I wrote an `IEnumerator<_>` that used `mutable` instead, but I won't bother posting it--the performance was (surprisingly) almost the same.

Answer (score 4):

Just initialize a unique collection (like a set) with the sequence like this:

```
set [1; 2; 3; 3; 4; 5; 5];;
=> val it : Set<int> = set [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I could not use Seq.distinct because I needed to preserve order of list elements.
I used solution from http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html.
I think it is quite short

```
let rec compress = function
    | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
    | smaller -> smaller
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below, preserves order of elements and returns only the first occurance of an element in a generic list.  Of course this generates a new List with the redundant items removed.

```
//  ****  Returns a list having subsequent redundant elements removed
let removeDuplicates(lst : 'a list) = 
    let f item acc =
        match acc with 
        | [] -> [item]
        | _ ->
            match List.exists(fun x -> x = item) acc with
            | false -> item :: acc
            | true -> acc
    lst 
    |> List.rev
    |> fun x -> List.foldBack f x []
    |> List.rev
//  **** END OF FUNCTION removeDuplicates

val removeDuplicates : 'a list -> 'a list when 'a : equality
val testList : int list = [1; 4; 3; 1; 2; 2; 1; 1; 3; 4; 3]
val tryAbove : int list = [1; 4; 3; 2]
```

Comment: dont match true/false just use if