# Find duplicates in an unsorted sequence efficiently

Tags: performance, algorithm, f#, ienumerable

I need a very efficient way to find duplicates in an unsorted sequence. This is what I came up with, but it has a few shortcomings, namely it

1. unnecessarily counts occurrences beyond 2
2. consumes the entire sequence before yielding duplicates
3. creates several intermediate sequences

```
module Seq = 
  let duplicates items =
    items
    |> Seq.countBy id
    |> Seq.filter (snd >> ((<) 1))
    |> Seq.map fst
```

Regardless of the shortcomings, I don't see a reason to replace this with twice the code. Is it possible to improve this with comparably concise code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicates in an F# sequence without using references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842466/how-can-i-remove-duplicates-in-an-f-sequence-without-using-references)

Comment: Actually, it's the inverse. I only want the duplicates.

Comment: Hmm, how do you want to store the values you have already visited? Set? Dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary/set are fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an imperative solution (which is admittedly slightly longer):

```
let duplicates items =
    seq {
        let d = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()
        for i in items do
            match d.TryGetValue(i) with
            | false,_    -> d.[i] <- false         // first observance
            | true,false -> d.[i] <- true; yield i // second observance
            | true,true  -> ()                     // already seen at least twice
    }
```

Comment: I kinda thought this is good as it gets, but figured it was worth asking.

Answer (score 10):

A more elegant functional solution:

```
let duplicates xs =
  Seq.scan (fun xs x -> Set.add x xs) Set.empty xs
  |> Seq.zip xs
  |> Seq.choose (fun (x, xs) -> if Set.contains x xs then Some x else None)
```

Uses `scan` to accumulate sets of all elements seen so far. Then uses `zip` to combine each element with the set of elements before it. Finally, uses `choose` to filter out the elements that are in the set of previously-seen elements, i.e. the duplicates.

**EDIT**

Actually my original answer was completely wrong. Firstly, you don't want duplicates in your outputs. Secondly, you want performance.

Here is a purely functional solution that implements the algorithm you're after:

```
let duplicates xs =
  (Map.empty, xs)
  ||> Seq.scan (fun xs x ->
      match Map.tryFind x xs with
      | None -> Map.add x false xs
      | Some false -> Map.add x true xs
      | Some true -> xs)
  |> Seq.zip xs
  |> Seq.choose (fun (x, xs) ->
      match Map.tryFind x xs with
      | Some false -> Some x
      | None | Some true -> None)
```

This uses a map to track whether each element has been seen before once or many times and then emits the element if it is seen having only been seen once before, i.e. the first time it is duplicated.

Here is a faster imperative version:

```
let duplicates (xs: _ seq) =
  seq { let d = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(HashIdentity.Structural)
        let e = xs.GetEnumerator()
        while e.MoveNext() do
          let x = e.Current
          let mutable seen = false
          if d.TryGetValue(x, &seen) then
            if not seen then
              d.[x] <- true
              yield x
          else
            d.[x] <- false }
```

This is around 2× faster than any of your other answers (at the time of writing).

Using a `for x in xs do` loop to enumerate the elements in a sequence is substantially slower than using `GetEnumerator` directly but generating your own `Enumerator` is not significantly faster than using a computation expression with `yield`.

Note that the `TryGetValue` member of `Dictionary` allows me to avoid allocation in the inner loop by mutating a stack allocated value whereas the `TryGetValue` extension member offered by F# (and used by kvb in his/her answer) allocates its return tuple.

Comment: +1 for cleverness, but it performs significantly worse than my original solution.

Comment: @Daniel Oops, I forgot it is supposed to be efficient! :-)

Comment: Very nice micro-improvements to the imperative version. Incidentally, I'm pretty sure Keith (kvb) is a "he." :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the best "functional" solution I could come up with that doesn't consume the entire sequence up front.

```
let duplicates =
    Seq.scan (fun (out, yielded:Set<_>, seen:Set<_>) item -> 
        if yielded.Contains item then
            (None, yielded, seen)
        else
            if seen.Contains item then
                (Some(item), yielded.Add item, seen.Remove item)
            else
                (None, yielded, seen.Add item)
    ) (None, Set.empty, Set.empty)
    >> Seq.Choose (fun (x,_,_) -> x)
```

Comment: Why Seq.skip? You can replace the Seq.filter and Seq.map combination with Seq.choose

Comment: Nice catch, I forgot about choose.  The skip was an artifact of earlier code.

Comment: You can get rid of seen.Remove - probably gaining a little bit of speed, and then your solution would be like mine - sets will intersect - EXCEPT that my solution consume the sequence up front, and so I think yours is better (hence the +1).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sequence is finite, this solution requires one run on the sequence:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let duplicates items =
   let dict = Dictionary()
   items |> Seq.fold (fun acc item -> 
                             match dict.TryGetValue item with
                             | true, 2 -> acc
                             | true, 1 -> dict.[item] <- 2; item::acc
                             | _ -> dict.[item] <- 1; acc) []
         |> List.rev
```

You can provide length of the sequence as the capacity of `Dictionary`, but it requires to enumerate the whole sequence once more.

**EDIT:**
To resolve 2nd problem, one could generate duplicates on demand:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let duplicates items =
   seq {
         let dict = Dictionary()
         for item in items do
            match dict.TryGetValue item with
            | true, 2 -> ()
            | true, 1 -> dict.[item] <- 2; yield item
            | _ -> dict.[item] <- 1
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional solution:

```
let duplicates items = 
  let test (unique, result) v =
    if not(unique |> Set.contains v) then (unique |> Set.add v ,result) 
    elif not(result |> Set.contains v) then (unique,result |> Set.add v) 
    else (unique, result)
  items |> Seq.fold test (Set.empty, Set.empty) |> snd |> Set.toSeq
```

Comment: [1;1;1;2;3;4;4;5] causes this to print 1 twice.

Comment: Our algorithms are very similar except your sets intersect while mine are disjoint.  I wonder, which would be faster?