# F# Removing duplicates from list with function

Tags: list, f#

I want to create a function that takes a list and returns a list with removed duplicates.

```
let removedupes list1 =
  let list2 = []
  let rec removeduprec list1 list2 =
    match list1 with
    | [] -> list2
    | head :: tail when mem list2 head = false -> head :: removeduprec tail list2
    | _ -> removeduprec list1.Tail list2
  removeduprec list1 list2
```

Im using this "mem" function to go trough the list and see if the value already exists and in that case i want to continue with the recursion.

```
let rec mem list x = 
  match list with
  | [] -> false
  | head :: tail -> 
    if x = head then true else mem tail x
```

When i test this code i get

```
let list1 =  [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 2; 2; 2]
removedups list1;;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 2; 2; 2]
```

Im thinking that the "head :: removeduprec tail list2", but im quite new to f# so not completely sure how this works.

Comment: The simpler method is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842466/

Comment: Set doesn't contain duplicates. Maybe create set from list?

Comment: @Alex - One of the answers that I linked uses set.  The constructor gets rid of the duplicates for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I rewrote some of the logic to make things simpler.  The problem was that you needed to add things to `list2` as it was created, rather than afterwards - I moved the `::` to inside the call like so

```
let rec mem list x =
  match list with
  | [] -> false
  | head :: tail ->
    if x = head then true else mem tail x

let removedupes list1 =
  let rec removeduprec list1 list2 =
    match list1 with
    | [] -> list2
    | head :: tail when mem list2 head = false -> removeduprec tail (head::list2)
    | h::t -> removeduprec t list2
  removeduprec list1 []
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness: in F# 4.0 the `List` module now has the [`distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.distinct%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) function doing exactly what OP wants.

```
List.distinct [1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 3];;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3;]
```

Answer (score 6):

A complementary to [stackoverflow.com/questions/6842466](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842466) and [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151733/917053) approaches; less idiomatic, but fast and obvious:

```
let removeDups is =
    let d = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()
    [ for i in is do match d.TryGetValue i with
                     | (false,_) -> d.[i] <- (); yield i
                     | _ -> () ]
```

It removes duplicates from list of 1000000 elements having 100000 possible different values by

```
 Real: 00:00:00.182, CPU: 00:00:00.171, GC gen0: 14, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
```

**Update**: following [ildjarn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn) comment using `HashSet` in place of `Dictionary` boosts performance about twice amortized on the same data:

```
Real: 00:00:00.093, CPU: 00:00:00.093, GC gen0: 2, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
```

On the contrary, [using the set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158128/917053) literally as suggested on the same test case downsides performance **27x**:

```
Real: 00:00:02.788, CPU: 00:00:02.765, GC gen0: 100, gen1: 21, gen2: 1
```

Comment: Why Dictionary rather than HashSet?

Comment: Yup, you could use a set, and a `HashSet` is most probably what LINQ's `Distinct` (and probably `Seq.distinctBy`) uses internally.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks, somehow missed that. I've updated my answer with performance comparisons of using `HashSet` vs `Dictionary` vs F# `set`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from John is probably what you are looking for - it shows an idiomatic functional way to solve the problem. However, if you do not want to implement the functionality yourself, the easiest way would be to turn the list into a *set* (which cannot contain duplicates) and then back to list:

```
let list1 = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 2; 2; 2]
let list2 = List.ofSeq (set list1)
```

This is probably the shortest solution :-) one difference from John's version is that this does not preserve the original ordering of the list (it actually sorts it).

Comment: To preserve the original ordering, you can also use: 
let list2 = list1 |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toList.