# I have two list (list a and list b) , with different lengths, how do i get a new list with all the unique elements of list a?

Tags: f#

I have this issue where i need a new list with, all the unique elements from list a, but the issue is that the list have different lengths.

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem? Why is the length of the list a factor in this?

Comment: Please provide a code sample, what you have tried so far. By your description, the list b does not have any relevance, all you need is to remove duplicates from List a, for what there is a number of methods.
Please review this page when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've tried a for-loop pattern matching, List.exist etc. etc but no luck so far

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't formulated correctly, but i need to compare the two list, and all of the items that aren't in list b, needs to be in a seperate list.

Comment: Edit your question because it is not clear and add the code snippets. Also look at Seq.distinct or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151535/f-removing-duplicates-from-list-with-function

Comment: I sincerely appreciate you help, thanks!

Comment: We should gently nudge new people towards asking more complete questions rather than downvote.  This is a small, friendly community.  Plus the initial F# learning curve is steep and it can be hard to come up with code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ 1; 2; 4; 5 ] |> List.except [ 2; 3; 5 ] // [ 1; 4 ]
```

That is, the following should do what you want

```
let c = a |> List.except b
```

### Update

As @rcoy pointed out, `List.except` returns *distinct* elements only, i.e.

```
[ 1; 1 ] |> List.except [] = [ 1 ] // true
```

To keep duplicates, a straightforward way is

```
let b = [ 2 ]
let toRemove x = not(List.contains x b)
[ 1; 1; 2 ] |> List.filter toRemove // [ 1; 1 ]
```

Depending on the size of the `b` list and equivalency function (structural vs. referential), i.e. the cost of traversing and comparing, changing the datastructures might be beneficial. E.g.

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let b = [ 2 ]
let toRemove = HashSet(b)
[ 1; 1; 2 ] |> List.filter (fun x -> not(toRemove.Contains(x))) // [ 1; 1 ]
```

which is similar to what `List.except` does internally.

Comment: This has the (possibly) surprising behavior of de-duplicating the source list.  Using `List.where` and `List.exists` may be the only way around that.